# How to check if two variables exist in an element of an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have two variables, Time and date. I'm checking if the given Time and Date from post exist in the database. So do `SELECT Time, Date` on database and storing the result in the array `result[]`.

Every element contains a time and day. **I tried**:

```
if (in_array($TimePost, $result)) {
```

but it doesn't work. And I also need to add in this statement the other variable which is the day. Is there any other way of checking this?

Comment: A sensible answer depends upon the datatypes of the columns in the Table and the format of the 2 variables that are holding the Date and Time. Can you show us the code and example data for the variables

Answer (score 2):

Just use two in_array statements.

```
in_array($TimePost, $result) && in_array($DatePost, $result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I first tried it in a different php file so codes for querying is prone to SQL injection, I just use this for functionality.

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $AptTime = $_POST['Time'];
 $AptDate = $_POST['Date'];
$sqlTime= "SELECT Time,Date FROM AppointmentTable Where Status = 'Unfinished' ";
$resultTime = mysqli_query($con,$sqlTime);
$TimeArr= array();
while ($dataTime = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTime))
{
$TimeArr[] = $dataTime;

}

if(in_array($AptTime , $TimeArr)){
echo 'Exists';

}
else{
  echo 'Does not';
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add like in your query

Example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Time LIKE '%time%' and  Date LIKE '%date%';
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. I only need to (mysqli_num_rows($resultTime)>0) for checking.

Comment: How is this related to the question? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it?